# zero inflated poisson regression AIC values

Tags: count-data, zero-inflation, statsmodels

Im trying to regress count data (DV). There are a few IV's both continuous and categorical. Frequency count of my DV as show below.Two groups , treatment and control. About 75 % are zeros.

```
#########
0     322
1      5
2     26
3     12
4      8
5      1
#########
```

Conditional mean

```
ACTIVE     0.381166
PLACEBO    0.520362

Name: hosp_visits, dtype: float64
```

Conditional variance

```
ACTIVE     0.696400
PLACEBO    0.877993
```

Conditional variance of the DV is a little bigger than conditional mean so I chose zero inflated poisson regression but AIC values are really bad

```
onemore_mdl = PoissonZiGMLE.from_formula("full_data.hospvisits ~ continuous_var1 + contunous_var2 + C(cateorical_var1) + count_variable1  ", data=full_data).fit()

onemore_mdl.summary()

Model:  PoissonZiGMLE
AIC:     787.9
Method:  Maximum Likelihood
BIC:     812.5
```

No. Observations:
443

Df Residuals:
438

Df Model:
4

Any suggestions on improving the model accuracy?

Comment: What do you mean AIC values are really bad? A singular AIC value doesn't have any relevance on its own, only relative to other values of AIC.

Comment: Hi there , My bad I thought I added the line that I have been adding more independent variables but AIC isn't improving , more or less stangant , hence the dilemma if there are any transformations that I could use and such. More over P values for more than a couple of independent values are > 0.20 threshold I had

Comment: one possibility is to make the zero inflation probability depend on explanatory variables. statsmodels 0.9 has more count models http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/discretemod.html#module-statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model

Comment: Thank you so much , I'm testing for over dispersion and like you mentioned i'm going to see if  zero inflated negative binomial does any better. @josef , I know I  sound lazy when I ask this , can you direct me on how to "make the zero inflation probability depend on explanatory variables."

Comment: use the `exog_infl` keyword http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.count_model.ZeroInflatedPoisson.html

Comment: Try reading this comment https://pubpeer.com/publications/8C7718F0A6B4D21EE753C569F46995 and that paper. I'm concerned that you haven't done the exploratory graphs and hard thinking required to implement zero inflated models, that you are simply chasing some impressive result. Have a good plan before you start applying models!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I could use non linear transformation of one of the independent variable. using patsy dmatrix and playing around with degrees of freedom on continous varaible helped.